# Selenium WebDriver, why is a complete relative XPath clickable, but a partial one isn't?

Tags: html, selenium

I have two XPath's of the same element, a complete one:

`//body/div[@class='body-widget']/div[@class='pseudo-popup-border']/div[@class='campaign competition language-en ng-scope']/div[@class='popup-blocks-container']/div[@class='popup-block']/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@class='ng-scope']/div/div/div[@class='ng-scope']/form[@name='contestantForm']/fieldset[@class='center']/div[@class='center login-choice login-types-4']/ul/li[1]/a[1]`

and a partial one

`"//div[@class='center login-choice login-types-4']/ul/li[1]/a[1]"`

which is the last part of the complete one.

When I use the complete path, I can retrieve the element and `click` it. However, when I use the partial path, selenium throws an exception `Message: Element <a class="no-underline facebook-bg popup-window" href="javascript:void(0)"> could not be scrolled into view`.

Even when I try to use something like a wait for the element to be clickable, I get the same problem. What is causing this?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that your XPaths are actually locating different elements on the page, and element located through relative path is not the correct one. `.click()` method is unaware of how the element was located, so absolute vs. relative XPath is not the issue here. You can use an XPath helper extension to test your XPaths on browser page to see what elements are getting located to troubleshoot the issue. Or,  you can post the HTML / or a link to the page you are automating, and we can help try to determine the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the absolute path, selenium knows the exact html structure through which it needs to find the element but when you are using the relative path, selenium is searching for the `center login-choice login-types-4` in the whole html structure and usually that also works but in your case, you are getting the exception `Element could not be scrolled into view` because the whole div of the element is not in the view or it is scrolled partially and hence the selenium is not able to click on it.

To solve your issue, you can first scroll to the element using `JavaScriptExecutor scroll` method and then you can click on that element and it would work fine
OR
You can directly click on the element using `JavaScriptExecutor click` method (but it is not recommend)